# regex replacing several special characters

Tags: regex

I am trying to find all characters that are either numbers or letters as well as `.` and `-` and `_`

here's whhat i tried:

```
[^A-Za-z0-9\.\-\_]
```

this does not work.

when i do everything except for `-` and `_`

```
[^A-Za-z0-9\.]
```

then it DOES work

can you please assist me with this expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 /[\w\.\-]/
```

Match word-characters (letter, number, underscore), dots and `-`

Answer (score 0):

```
[^A-Za-z0-9\.\-_]
```

the underscore doesn't need escaping.

Comment: it looks like the dash ignored!